# Is it possible to lay anti-tank mines in a way that can't be seen by enemy tank drivers?

Tags: battlefield-3

I know that anti-tank mines are observable by drivers with thermal optics, and you can even "spot" them. Sometimes I just happen to see mines myself, so, is it possible to lay mines in such a way, that the driver will not see them, but run over them ? Can the terrain be used effectively to do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At first I would say that it depends on the driver and if he has a good gunner or some people running next to him. Besides that there are some several points you can keep in mind when placing your mines:

- place the mines on dark coloured underground, so that is harder to see them
- don't place them directly on the road or on the typical driveways
- place them close to the end of an uphill road, so that the tank/car will still be in an upwards-angle so that the driver can't look down to the road
- use the map to hide the mines: place them near "decoration", in higher grass, in water to hide the mines or in the craters created by explosions, so they are hidden from sight
- put them on spots where people normally drive fast to breach through, so there is no time to react or evade the mines

All this won't guarantee any minekill, but increase the chance of some kills. I hope it helps!

Comment: Just to add one missed point. You can place them in the craters created by explosions, so they are hidden from sight.

Answer (score 7):

Like the claymore mines, you can hide AT mines in or near deployed ammo/heath packs using the pack as a camouflage.  However, this usually requires a buddy as an assault/support to help you out.  The packs don't normally last long out in the open.

The AT mines are good at destroying vehicles, but more importantly they slow/stop the forward progression of a tank.  This is a commonly overlooked tactic.  You can use the mines to direct a vehicle to slow down or stop where you want it to.  Setting up the vehicle so that it is in the perfect position for an RPG/SMAW ambush.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in points where someone just rushes through: On Caspian Border I always get killed goping to the Russian Gimme Flag on the Road going down from the RU Deployment. I just rush in there with a Jeep and go Rambo but I get blown up Sky High. Anyway you can even put mines to stop the Driver: I've been ambushed when blowing up a Minefield in a tank.